# How to read a keypair generated by `keytool`?

Tags: go, jwt

Our app using JWT tokens signed by RSA key and we generated a keypair using Java's `keytool`. We're rebuilding a few APIs in `go` and trying to figure out how to read the generated keypair using go so that we can validate the tokens.

How do we go about building this - are there any APIs in go or should we resort to any third-party libraries?

Comment: The java keytool keeps certs in a proprietary file format, but I think you can find instructions on using java/keytool/openssl to export the keys to a more standard format.

Comment: The best way to go is to transform it into a PKCS12 store that you can consume with [x/crypto/pkcs12](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/pkcs12).

From [stackexchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3779/how-can-i-export-my-private-key-from-a-java-keytool-keystore):
`keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore existing-store.jks -destkeystore new-store.p12 -deststoretype PKCS12`